# Not able to access the static IP from local internet service provider's internet

Tags: isp

Our one of static IP from Tata lease line is natted (i.e. configured in firewall) for our virtual server IP and we are using this IP globally as an RDP for ERP access. But currently we are not able to access this IP from the internet which we have recently taken in that location from the local internet service provider. Traceroute report shows that tatadc.co.in blocking this IP. 
But from BSNL broadband we can access this IP. The local service provider has Airtel and Vodafone bandwidth. Can anybody explain the reason behind this.

Comment: Is that IP address assigned by the Local ISP? An ISP will only advertise it's own addresses, or any of yours which it has agreed to advertise, usually through BGP.

Comment: Please clarify your question. To start, I suggest you to specify which are private and public IP addresses in your context. Are you managing your BGP routes?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check the circuit info again to verify everything along with your BGP configuration....Also is this a new issue or did the interface pass traffic until recently and then just cease functioning?

To me this sounds like a routing issue, I agree with Ron. This would explain why it works from one ISP and not another. If it is not configured correctly for this particular ISP most likely a BGP issue the static IP is not going to be reachable.

One other consideration is proper rule implementation at the FW..if I understand this right there was a different ISP or something along those lines...or this was a new acquisition, in that case you may need to validate your FW rules to make sure they are ideal to accomodate this new site.